# How to NOT write file_put_contents on EVERY page load

Tags: php, joomla, templating, output-buffering

I am completely new to PHP (2 weeks) and I have created a simply script for Joomla that will save parameters from my my admin area options and put those values into a CSS format and save the file. It's a whole long script of CSS but here's an example of it...

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<?php
////////////// Custom colours set from the admin panel
if ($this->params->get('templateColor'))
{
?>
/* <?php echo($template); ?>: Custom Auto-Generated CSS Colors As Set in Admin Template     Parameters */

body.site {
border-top: 3px solid <?php echo $this->params->get('templateColor');?>;
background-color: <?php echo $this->params->get('templateBackgroundColor');?>
}
<?php
}
?>
 <?php

$googlefontcss = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents('templates/'.$template.'/css/googlefonts.css', $googlefontcss);
?>
```

Heres my problem, all of these things are stored in a helper file which is called from my index file, but this has the effect that the CSS file is created every time that the page is loaded rather than when I adjust and save my params in the backend. Surely, if I got a lot of traffic, this is going to stress the server even though the css file is quite short (its longer than shown here).

Being a newbie, I have no idea how I would avoid this problem and instead only have the file written when the options are changed and saved. Anybody suggest a better way?

Comment: Can't you move that code to some place where it's executed after you change CSS? If not you can always use `file_get_contents` on the same file, compare it with `$googlefontcss` and do `file_put_contents` only if they do not match... but with large file it can take more resources then simple rewrite. You can also put some flag after saving CSS and use it to save file only if it's set, then after saving change it back. Anyway, as i said before, moving this code to backend to be executed after CSS save would be better idea.

Comment: put an if statement around the code and check if you have submitted something new, I'm not sure how the form looks like that you have created for the submission

Comment: I can only set params for the Joomla backend - not add code to the actual template options files without modifying the Joomla core which I do not want to do. Joomla write the results of what is saved from the options in the backend to the params and I can get them at any time. However, I have no "event" as such with which to write them other than the inevitable frontend page refresh that a person will do to check their adjustments that I can think of.

Comment: I lack experience of knowing how these kinds of problems are usually tackled to know how to ask the right kind of question I suppose.

Comment: If you can't / dont want to modify backend and you get CSS in variable to be used in frontend, then you have to either rewrite file every time or - which would be better - instead of writing CSS to the file and using this file in `<link>`, you can print that variable in `<style>` tag directly, bypassing the file. This will also prevent browsers from caching your CSS, what you probably want if you change it often in backend.

Comment: Could I not write the params to say a session, then on page load, get the session contents, write them to a file and then dump the session contents?

Comment: I'm really confused about why you would do this at all.  First, Joomla has a way to save parameters for a template and to use them. It also has a standard way to include a css file in your template. You can do this easily with a plugin if you don't want to addStyle() directly to the  the template file.

I really think you need to look at how templates work in Joomla --- it's not modifying the core to modify your template index unless you are using one of the included templates --- in which case copy it whihc you can do with one click in 2.5 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really confused about why you would do this at all.  First, Joomla has a way to save parameters for a template and to use them, which you are doing. It also has a standard way to include a css file in your template. You can do this easily with a plugin if you don't want to addStyle() directly to the  the template file. Also for google font api just look at how protostar does it.

I really think you need to look at how templates work in Joomla --- it's not modifying the core to modify your template index unless you are using one of the included templates --- in which case copy it, which you can do with one click in 2.5 and 3.

If you really absolutely have to do this, make a plugin. There are a lot of examples in the JED of plugins to include a file in a template. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/head-code

Comment: I do not want to edit the core at all. I am doing it because I want parameters set in the admin to create & write the user's settings as css to a separate css file and not simply add <style> tags to the head of the document which makes for ugly source code and is generally frowned upon. I have found a way, as demonstrated, to create and edit a separate css file from parameter settings, my only concern is that this re-creates the css file every time the page is loaded. All Joomla templates I have seen write styles to the head which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way, to override the template options in the admin, simply to include my file_put_contents event so that the css file was only created/over-written when the parameters are updated and saved - creating a new css file which is then called in the head of my template. This would avoid the file having to be recreated every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Like I said, changing your template is not editing the core.  Make a copy and edit.  You can also use a plugin to load whatever  you want.  So here's what I'll say first. You say you are new to joomla and php. To start with, use the api, don't fight it. Joomla makes it easy to do things like change the background color either to a fixed list or with the color picker. Look at protostar and beez as examples. Do not look at commercial templates since they are too complex. What you are thinking is a cool idea especially with LESS in the picture. It would be cool to set a LESS var in the style ui.